# Require Xcode version to develop iOS 6 applications for iPad 4th Gen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios6

I need to develop iOS application for iPad 4th generation which works on iOS 6.

Currently my system configuration are as follows
1. MAC OS X Version : macOS Sierra (10.12.4)
2. Xcode Version : 8.3.3

I think I need to download previous xcode version to develop iOS 6 applications.

Can anyone kindly help me out what xcode version and macOS version are required to me to install to develop iOS 6 apps?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPad_(4th_generation) : Original: iOS 6.0.1
Current: iOS 10.3.3 - you can support the latest versions of iOS for iPad 4th Gen or install Xcode 7 https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.3.1/Xcode_7.3.1.dmg

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can develop apps for iPad(iOS 6) 4th Generation and install the app as enterprise app for your devices.

For that, you need to install Xcode 4.x and iOS 6 SDK.

**But you can't upload the app to the Apple store as it supports the minimum version of Xcode6.**

For more details about xcode version and the dependent Mac os details, please visit this wiki link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode.